# Julia - replace

Tags: replace, julia

I have tried the following method and it worked.

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[5,6,7]

for i=1:3
    a=replace(a,a[i]=>b[i]*a[i])
end
```

The result showed: a=[5,12,21], which is the product I wanted,elementwise product.

However, I tried to use the same method for getting the product I want but it didn't work.

```
a=[]
for i=1:10
    a=push!(a,2^i)
end

for i=1:10
    a=replace(a,a[i]=>a[i]*a[i])
end
```

But the result is

```
a=[65536,65536,4096,65536,1048576,4096,16384,65536,262144,1048576]
```

And I want to yield

```
a=[4,16,64,256,1024,4096,16384,65536,262144,1048576]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just want to use `a .= a .* a`? Most people will find this much cleaner

Comment: Dear Oscar Smith, thank you for your answer! :) I haven't tried this one! Cuz I will have another for loop outside of this operation, so I not really sure how this works, with the operation you suggest.

Comment: the thing to look up in the docs is broadcasting basically `.` makes operations apply element-wise.

Comment: OK! Thank you very much!~  :)

Comment: It works! Thank you sooo much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is, that `replace` might not do what you want. The command

```
replace(A, old => new)
```

takes a collection `A` and creates a new collection where every occurrence of `old` is replaced by `new`.

So if we look at your example, in the first iteration we replace every occurrence of `a[1] == 2` by `4`. This yields

```
a == [4, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
```

In the second iteration, we replace every occurrence of `a[2] == 4` by `16`. This yields

```
a == [16, 16, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
```

and so on. This should explain why you get that weird result.

Apart from the broadcasts `a .= a .* a` or `a .= a .^ 2` that Oscar Smith mentioned in his comment, you could also use the functions `map`

```
a = map(x -> x^2, a)
```

or `map!`:

```
map!(x -> x^2, a, a)
```

The difference between `map` and `map!` is, that `map` creates a new version and `map!` writes to an already existing collection. In this example, the input collection is the same as the output collection.

Comment: Thanks, Simon! It's well-explained! Now I got it! :)